# pythons 'print' statement doesn't call the .write() method?

Tags: python, oop, file, inheritance, printing

I thought the `print` statement just called the .write() method on the `sys.stdout` (by default) object.

but having written a subclass like this:

```
import time

class logfile(file):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        file.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def write(self, logstr):
        if logstr[-1] != '\n': logstr += '\n'
        super(logfile, self).write(time.strftime('%D-%T ') + str(logstr))
```

It seems to work if I create a `logfile` object and call the `write` method, but when trying to change the `sys.stdout` object to an instance of the `logfile` it appears as though `print` isn't calling `write`. Maybe `writelines`?

Using this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from myfile import logfile
import sys

sys.stdout = logfile('somefile', 'w')

print 'this is a test'
sys.stdout.write('this is another test')
```

My output file 'somefile' contains:

```
this is a test
08/10/11-16:59:47 this is another test
```

You can see the first line in the output file is what I tried to `print` and the second line is what was used in `sys.stdout.write`

I thought `print` just called the `write` method- clearly I'm missing something basic.

Comment: Is http://stefaanlippens.net/redirect_python_print helping?

Comment: `print` has it's own reference to `stdout`.

Comment: @Evpok I think if he's trying to redirect print instead of using normal logging he probably doesn't want to modify pre-existing `print` statements.

Comment: You should use the logging module for logging to a file. Much more configurable.

Comment: Are you avoiding Python's logging module on purpose, or is this just an exercise in an alternative implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is an limitation of the implementation of Python 2 where print is a statement rather than an expression with side-effects (as it is in Python 3).

I rewrote the code to something that works in Python 3:

```
from io import FileIO
import time

class logfile(FileIO):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    FileIO.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

  def write(self, logstr):
    if logstr[-1] == '\n': logstr = logstr[:-1]
    super(logfile, self).write(bytes(time.strftime('%D-%T ') + str(logstr), 'UTF-8'))

import sys

sys.stdout = logfile('somefile', 'w')

print("This is a test")
sys.stdout.write('this is another test')
```

As far as I know there is no way to create the same behaviour in Python 2.

I also tried using `from __future__ import print_function` but that made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the file in an instance variable, it seems to work.

```
import time

class logfile(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.f = file(*args, **kwargs)
    def write(self, logstr):
        if logstr[-1] != '\n': logstr += '\n'
        self.f.write(time.strftime('%D-%T ') + str(logstr))
```

Unfortunately it logs extra empty lines, here is one solution (`print '2', '3', '4'` writes 3 entries):

```
class logfile(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.f = file(*args, **kwargs)
        self.c = False
    def write(self, logstr):
        self.c = not self.c
        if logstr[-1] != '\n': logstr += '\n'
        if self.c:
            self.f.write(time.strftime('%D-%T ') + str(logstr))
```

This one logs full lines (note: `print "4\n", "5"` is still 2 loglines):

```
class logfile(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.f = file(*args, **kwargs)
        self.newline = True
    def write(self, logstr):
        if self.newline:
            self.f.write(time.strftime('%D-%T '))
        self.f.write(logstr)
        self.newline = logstr[-1] == '\n'
```

Does anybody know how to handle full print statements in 1 loglines?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/python-tee.html) explains your problem.  Basically if `sys.stdout` is a subclass of `file` then `print` bypasses `sys.stdout.write` and writes directly to `sys.stdout.fd`.

The solution to your problem is to use composition instead of subclassing `file`.